# Display dates for a long period on the graph

Tags: usability, web-app, design-patterns

I'm working on an app where I need to show a graphs for different period of time. The problem is that when I'm picking long periods like a 5 or 6 months, the labels for days are all squished together and it's impossible to read them. How will it be better, but still informative to show the period of time on X axis instead of showing every day?

So I need to make sure that user will understand what are the dates shown.

[image: screenshot with the current look]

Comment: Hello Nick, I'd suggest you to provide the graph's ideal (the date labels are readable) illustration, otherwise it just doesn't make sense for me completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it would be useful if you take a look at how Google Analytics solved this kind of problem: the individual days only show up if you hover your mouse directly over the data points. Meanwhile, your x-axis will now only show the name of the months.

[image: Google Analytics]